# MySQL inline if statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that selects the name, description, date, etc of an item from a single table. This table has a field named "archived". If a row has a 1 in the archived field, it means that it's archived.

I currently use this code here to display my list of items, whether it's archived or not:

```
<?php
        // Request the text for zz
        $result = @mysql_query("SELECT oc_sysitem,oc_item,oc_itemdesc,oc_genre,oc_star,oc_alttxt,oc_iearchived,oc_url FROM catalog WHERE oc_sysitem LIKE('zz') ORDER BY oc_sysitem DESC, oc_item, oc_setnum +0 ASC");

        if (!$result) {
            exit('<p>Error performing query: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
        }
        //creating the table w/ headers
        echo '
        <table cellpadding="3px">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:360px;font-weight:bold"><p>Title</p></td>
            <td style="width:90px;font-weight:bold"><p>Genre</p></td>
            <td style="width:70px;font-weight:bold"><p>System</p></td>
            <td style="width:51px;font-weight:bold"><p>Rating</p></td>
        </tr>';     
        // Display each zz
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '
        <tr title="' . $row['oc_item'] . ' ' . $row['oc_itemdesc'] . ', ' . $row['oc_alttxt'] . '" class="tblhover">
            <td style="width:360px"><a href="' . $row['oc_url'] .'" rel="nofollow">' . $row['oc_item'] . ' ' . $row['oc_itemdesc'] . '</a></td>
            <td style="width:90px">' . $row['oc_genre'] . '</td>
            <td style="width:70px">' . $row['oc_sysitem'] . '</td>
            <td style="width:51px"><img src="../../media/ocdb/' . $row['oc_star'] . '" alt="' . $row['oc_alttxt'] . '" title="' . $row['oc_alttxt'] . '" /></td>
        </tr>
        ';
        }       
        echo '</table>';        
        ?>
```

I want to be able to display an asterisk next to the title if it is archived. I have not been able to figure out how to add an if statement or if that right path to take. Any advice would be welcomed, thank you.

Answer (score 13):

There is the `IF` function for MySQL:

`if(expr1, expr2, expr3)`

if `expr1` is `TRUE` it returns `expr2`, else it returns `expr3`

see **[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)** for more details

Comment: 404 on the link

Answer (score 5):

you can do this in sql

example:

```
CASE WHEN Archived = 1 THEN Title + '*' ELSE Title END As Title
```

In your case

```
CASE WHEN oc_iearchived = 1 THEN oc_item + ' ' + oc_itemdesc + '*' 
ELSE oc_item + ' ' + oc_itemdesc END As [Title]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Ternary if statement can make this simple in PHP.

```
 $title = $row['oc_item'] . ' ' . $row['oc_itemdesc'] . ', ' . $row['oc_alttxt'] . $row['oc_iearchived'] == 1 ? '*' : '';
 echo '
 <tr title="' . $title . '" class="tblhover">  
 //etc
```

Comment: This is what I get when I use the code:   '" class="tblhover"> " class="tblhover"> " class="tblhover"> " class="tblhover"> " class="tblhover"> " class="tblhover"> '

Comment: Try breaking up the very long string that you are echoing. There may be a problem with the delimiters somewhere. I modified the answer slightly to see if that improves the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks- I've updated my code, the broken HTML is fixed, however the * does not show.

Comment: Check the condition of your if statement. Maybe try printing out the value before just to see that you are getting what you expect to get.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend that you not do this in SQL -- it's just as easy to select the `archived` field and print an asterisk at the view layer (i.e, in PHP) if it's set. Pushing this functionality to the database doesn't really make a lot of sense, especially for something this trivial, and doing so would make adding other functionality later (e.g, changing the styling of the asterisk) more difficult.